# Show that f(M) is a compact space

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity

I am studying set theory and I have a problem I would like help with. I have tried setting it up but have not progressed with it. I usually progress and that's why it bothers me.
So here goes:

Show that if $M$ and $N$ are metric spaces, $M$ is compact and $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a continuous function that $f(M)$ is a compact subspace of $N$.

The definition of compactness is if the space satisfies either (hence both) equivalent conditions that:

a. Every sequence has a convergent subsequence.

b. Every infinite set has a limit point.

So I guess that $f: M \rightarrow N$ carries all of the points to $N$, and so $f(M) ⊆ N$ also contains these points (especially the limit points). And therefore it is compact. But surely this is completely wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's stick to definition a.  Our proof should then be structured as follows: it should start with

> Let $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $f(M)$.

We should somehow end this proof by demonstrating that $(y_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.  Here's what my proof would look like (I'll leave it to you to fill in the blanks):

> Let $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence in $f(M)$.  By definition of $f(M)$, there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$.  $(x_n)$ has a convergent sequence $(x_{n_k})_{k=1}^\infty$ (why is this true?)  We can then conclude that the sequence $(y_{n_k}) = (f(x_{n_k}))$ is convergent (why?).  Note that this is a subsequence of $(y_n)$.  Thus, an arbitrary sequence $(y_n) \subset f(M)$  must have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: To answer your questions, $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence by definition? Since $M$ being compact, $x_n$ is a sequence of $M$ and thus it has a convergent subsequence? If not, it would not be compact (?). And the $y_{n_k}$ should be convergent since continuous functions assure that if $x_{n_k}$ converges then $f(x_{n_k})$ also converges? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: 1. by the definition **of compactness**, yes.  And yes, you got the second one too.  Same idea as the other answer.  Hope this gives you an idea of how to approach these proofs when you get stuck like this again.

Comment: Great. Yes I believe it will, this pushed me in the right direction. Very helpful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Any sequence in $f(M)$ can be written as $f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots$.

By compactness of $M$, the sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ has a convergence subsequence $x_{k_1},x_{k_2},\ldots$. By continuity of $f$, the sequence $f(x_{k_1}),f(x_{k_2}),\ldots$ also converges.

Comment: I see. Seems obvious when you spelled it out. And since $f(x_{k})$... converges it satisfies that condition that it has a convergent subsequence.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This works even in a more general setting, using the most general definitions of continuity and compactness. Concretely:

- $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open for every open set $V$
- $M$ is compact if every open cover admits a finite sub-cover.

If now you are given an open cover of $f(M)$, the preimages will form an open cover of $M$, and thus have a finite sub-cover. Then you can push the finite sub-cover to $f(M)$ to obtain a finite sub-cover of the original cover.

Comment: I like this version of the proof better too.

Comment: Ah I understand. These steps does not seem as obvious as the other answer (and that is all because of me), but when you spell it out I can make sense of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Given a sequence of points $y_i\in f(M)$, it suffices to show it has a convergent subsequence. For each $i$, choose a point $x_i \in M$ with $f(x_i)=y_i$; this forms a sequence in $M$. Since $M$ is compact, there is a convergent subsequence $x_{i_k}\to x\in M$. By continuity, $y_{i_k}=f(x_{i_k})\to f(x)\in f(M)$.